# missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

```
class Keys():
    def __init__(self):
        self.key_list = {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"}
    def get_name(self, key):
       self.ddd = key

key1 = Keys
key1.get_name(1)
```

Why, after starting this code, do I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 8, in <module>
    key1.get_name(1)
TypeError: get_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

I am using Python 3.

Comment: Way of creating class's instance is wrong. It should be `key1 = Keys()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
class Keys():
    def __init__(self):
        self.key_list = {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"}
    def get_name(self, key):
       self.ddd = key

key1 = Keys()
key1.get_name(1)
```

Note the use of parenthesis: `key1 = Keys()`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parens:

```
class Keys():
    def __init__(self):
        self.key_list = {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"}
    def get_name(self, key):
       self.ddd = key

key1 = Keys() # <- missing parens
key1.get_name(1)
```